# Class member initialization C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

I want to initialize transform variable when creating theGameObject, but something is going wrong. Compiler says:

```
C3646   'transform' : unknown override specifier    (line 4)
C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    (line 4)
C3861   'Transform': identifier not found    (line 5)
C2614   'GameObject' : illegal member initialization: 'transform' is not a base or member    (line 5)

    1.    class GameObject
    2.    {
    3.    public:
    4.        Transform transform;
    5.        GameObject() : transform(Transform()) {}
    6.    };
    7.
    8.    class Transform
    9.    {
   10.    public:
   11.        Vector3 position;
   12.        Vector3 rotation;
   13.        Vector3 dimension;
   14.
   15.        Transform()
   16.        {
   17.            position = Vector3();
   18.            rotation = Vector3();
   19.            dimension = Vector3();
   20.        }
   21.    }
```

In main.cpp I call:

```
GameObject theGameObject = GameObject();
```

What I've done wrong?

Comment: You do remember that to be able to use a symbol it has to be declared or maybe even defined *before* you use it? So try changing the order of the two class definitions and see if it works better.

Comment: A [mcve] is always a good adition to a question...

Comment: The problem is that GameObject class is declared in GameObject.h and Transform class in Transform.h
GameObject.h as #include "Transform.h", so I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Resolved. I included both "Transform.h" in "GameObject.h and "GameObject.h" in Transform.h
I feel stupid.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

In your `GameObject` class you have a `Transform` object `Transform transform;` but the compiler hasn't seen the `Transform` class yet and thus it doesn't know it's size or what it even is. You should define `Transform` and then `GameObject` instead of `GameObject` and then `Transform`. You probably want to seperate these classes in individual header files too.

---

Side note:
You can just do `GameObject theGameObject;` too.